# Import GAE data through Storage into BigQuery fails

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

In Google App Engine I created a backup using the Datastore Admin. I selected Google Cloud Storage as the destination and now I have a bucket with my backup.

Now I'm trying to import that data into BigQuery.

On the website I created a new dataset and clicked "Create new table". At the "Select data" step I selected AppEngine Datastore Backup and "Load data from Google Cloud Storage gs://mybucket".

At that point I always get this error:

"Source URI must be a Google-Storage location: gs://mybucket"

On the site the bucket seems just fine:
https://storage.cloud.google.com/

And `gsutil ls gs://mybucket` also works, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Is there still some other ACL or something that I need to set?

Comment: Did you try with a trailing / ?

Comment: Yes. Got the same error message.

Comment: Do you have any strange characters in the bucket name?

Comment: No, only lowercase alphanumeric. No underscores or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the full path to the backup_info file.

For instance, the location could be something like this:

```
gs://my_bucket/RhdGFzd9yS1hZ1pbi1vem.ReservationData.backup_info
```

You should be able to see this filename when you execute your `gsutil ls gs://mybucket` command.

Comment: Is there also a way to import all tables at once? Right now I have to import ...AQw.Table1.backup_info and then ...AQw.Table2.backup_info. I noticed there's also a ...AQw.backup_info file but I can't import that one.

Comment: No, unfortunately the imports are on a per-table basis-- as a BigQuery job currently only operates on a single table. So, you couldn't import multiple tables at once into different BQ tables.

Comment: How do I select individual table from a full backup? Or should I backup one by one

Comment: I clicked on backup info in Datastore admin, used /gs/bucket/xxxxBDA.backup_info does not contain valid backup metadata.